# How to get standard errors of linear regression coefficients subject to linear equality constraints

Tags: regression-coefficients, standard-error, constrained-regression

I have a regression problem with multiple sets of sum-to-one categorical features (e.g. X1=Male, X2=Female, X3=Weekday, X4=Weekend), intercept needs to be included as well as some restrictions on the coefficient dummy groups. Say B_X1 + B_X2 = 0 and B_X3 + B_X4 = 0. Given perfect collinearity in the design matrix X standard Lagrange multiplier method is not suitable as it requires inverting X^T X, thus augmented equations are used.

- Y = response variable [n x 1]
- X = matrix of features [n x k]
- β = vector of coefficients [k x 1]
- Z = restriction matrix [k x p]
- n = number of observations
- k = number of features
- p = number of restrictions

$$ min_β (Y-Xβ ̂ )^T(Y-Xβ ̂ ) \\
 ST \:  Z^T β ̂= 0   \\ 
\left[\begin{array}{c}
Y \\ 0 
\end{array}\right]
=
\left[\begin{array}{c}
X \\ Z^T 
\end{array}\right]
β \: + 
\left[\begin{array}{c}
ε \\ 0 
\end{array}\right]
\\
Least \: squares \: problem: 
\\
min_β\left(\left[\begin{array}{c}
Y \\ 0 
\end{array}\right] -
\left[\begin{array}{c}
X \\ Z 
\end{array} \right] β \right)^T
\left(\left[\begin{array}{c}
Y \\ 0 
\end{array}\right] -
\left[\begin{array}{c}
X \\ Z 
\end{array} \right] β \right) \\ ST \:Z^T β ̂= 0
$$
Taking first order conditions and solving for coefficient vector:
$$
β ̂=QX^TY \\
Q = M^{-1} - M^{-1}Z(Z^TM^{-1}Z)^{-1}Z^TM^{-1} \\
M = X^TX + ZZ^T
$$
I am looking for guidance on how to compute standard error of the coefficients which involves computing: $$VAR(β)$$

Comment: Why are you using 4 variables for this design matrix? You could define X1 to be 0 if Male and 1 if Female, and X2 to be 0 if Weekday and 1 if Weekend.

Comment: Mainly for economic interpretation/ business reasons, would like to keep the intercept and read the categorical group coefficients relative to that (subject to some constraint) instead of relative to an arbitrarily chosen reference group (i.e. take one category out)

Comment: What are $S$ and $T$ in $STZ^T \hat{\beta}$?

Comment: Nevermind. "ST" must mean subject to.

Comment: Your model isn't identifiable; you can't estimate the parameters. Adding a constraint *may* make the model identifiable, but you're making things too difficult. Why not fit a model with a sensible parameterization then take functions of your parameters to make the comparisons you're interested in?

Comment: Mainly due to strong economic interpretation (and significance), for instance in a financial application of equity factor model, where the intercept is read as the market and one has industries to be read as net-of-market coefficients and significance/inference of those net-of-market industry coefficients is required